# Append # at the beginning of a string generated by a velocity macro

Tags: jquery, macros, velocity

Does anybody know how to get a velocity macro to run when it's prepended by an Octothorpe?

I have a velocity macro called `#macro(getUniqueID $id)`

And I want to use it to spit out an id to be used by `jQuery.find()` which uses CSS selectors which means that the id needs to be prepended by another octothorpe.

```
jquery.find("##getUniqueID('id')")
```

dosn't work

nor does

```
\#set($id = #getUniqueID('id'))
jquery.find(#$id)
```

nor does

```
\#set($id = '#getUniqueID("id")')
jquery.find(#$id)
```

nor

```
\#set($id = "#getUniqueID('id')")
jquery.find(#$id)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experiments the following escaping should work for you:

```
<h2 id="#octothorpe">foo</h2>

$('#\\#octothorpe');
> [h2##octothorpe]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find a div by the id, you would need to do jQuery.find('#'+id) vs #id. Nevertheless, you can probably use the \ to escape your second hash symbol.